# Android Distinct SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, distinct

I have this code in my dbHelper class, I need to make it so that it returns Distinct values in the lesson_name column. however, none of the examples online show it in the format I've used for the query.

```
   public Cursor getLessonNames(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            Cursor cursor;
            String[] projections = {TimetableContract.NewTimetableInfo.LESSON_NAME};
            cursor = db.query(TimetableContract.NewTimetableInfo.TABLE_NAME, projections, null, null, null, null, null);
            return cursor;
        }
```

Comment: This is where you want to use `rawQuery()`, instead of `query()`. I.e.: `SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM ... WHERE ...`

Comment: Can I then just type the query as a string?

Comment: Yes, I added that to my previous comment.

Comment: Sorry can you type just that line as code please? its not liking it on my end

Comment: mind googling for `android rawquery`?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) shows that the `query()` method allows this:

> `distinct`    `boolean`: true if you want each row to be unique, false otherwise.